# Why does it keep looping

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, try-except

Im pretty new to coding and I don’t really know why this keeps looping. After you enter all the information, the code should give you the cost, put the order into the list, and stop, but the code loops back to “How many orders would you like to place?” How can I fix this?

```
              what_drink=input('What drinks would you like? ')
              if what_drink =='Lemonade' or 'Fountain Drinks':
                many3=int(input('How many would you like? '))
                cost3=round(((many3*adrink)+(adrink * tax)+cost2), 2)
                orderss=order,order2,what_drink
                print('Your total is $', cost3)
                orders.append(orderss)
                print(orders)
            if drinks =='No'and sides=='No':
              orderss=order,order2
              print('Your total is $', cost2)
              orders.append(orderss)
              print(orders)
              break
            else: print('Sorry, please enter a valid response, check the menu to see our products.')
      else: print('Sorry, please enter a valid response, check the menu to see our products.')
  except ValueError: #Error handling if the user inputs something incorrect
      print('Please enter a number')
```

Comment: `if what_drink =='Lemonade' or 'Fountain Drinks'` This is not doing what you think.

Comment: I can't see any code that prompt *“How many orders would you like to place?”*

Comment: Indentation is everything in Python, but your indentation is all over the place, and it looks like there is code missing at the top. Take the time to resolve the indentation and ensure your code is complete. Without this it's going to be difficult to answer you.